# What das "na" mean in dataframe.dropna() in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

*NA* means either *NaN* or *Null* from what I know.

I know that *NaN* means "Not a Number". Does *NA* stand for "**n**ot **a**vailable"? I didn't find anything about it online.

Comment: NA is not available

Comment: There's a reference to this [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html#values-considered-missing) under *Values considered “missing”*

Comment: You can find more detail when you search NA with `R`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quote from pandas [user guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html#missing-data):

*As data comes in many shapes and forms, pandas aims to be flexible with regard to handling missing data. While NaN is the default missing value marker for reasons of computational speed and convenience, we need to be able to easily detect this value with data of different types: floating point, integer, boolean, and general object. In many cases, however, the Python None will arise and we wish to also consider that **“missing” or “not available” or “NA”**.*